# Polymer WebApp hosted on Firebase after update to iOS 10 start from homescreen stops working

Tags: ios, firebase, polymer, firebase-hosting, polymer-starter-kit

A Polymer Progressive Web App based on PolymerStarterKit 1.3.0 works on all platforms (Windows with Chrome, Firebase, IE or MAC Safari, Android with Chrome and iOS with Safari etc).

After updating my Test-iPhone to iOS 10.0.2 it is no longer possible to start the application from the home screen. A blank screen is shown. 
When I use Safari on the iPhone, the page is displayed after a second load.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [issue](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/issues/617) reported on Github. Looks like the issue I have shown here. The hint comes from firebase-support.

News:
Updated webcomponentsjs in my app to 0.7.23. Same issue with my Test-iPhone5 iOS 10.x. as described above. Strange is that my users with iPhone6 or 6s have no problems using the app.